# update org.apache.upload.FormFile to struts2

Tags: struts2, struts

I am upgrading my application to struts2.Is there any package in struts2 which contains the FormFile class.I am getting compile exception due to this class?

Comment: Struts 2 is a completely different framework than Struts 1.

Answer (score 0):

`FormFile` is a class used in `struts` (not `struts2`) for file upload.

Consider the example below for file upload in `struts2` and change your code accordingly.

https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-file-upload-example/